# Date formatting Edge Browser

Tags: javascript, timezone, timezone-offset

The Output in `Chrome Browser`:

```
new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Jakarta',timeStyle:"long" })

//output : "11:06:47 PM GMT+7"
```

The output for `Edge Browser`:

```
 new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Jakarta',timeStyle:"long" })

//output : 10/17/2020, 11:02:40 PM"
```

Is there any way to achieve the same output as Chrome in Edge Browser?

Comment: Are you referring to the older non-Chromium version of Edge? It simply doesn't support `timeStyle`.  The newer Chromium-based version gives the same result as Chrome.

Comment: Yes, an older version of Edge. Is there any other way? To achieve this?

Comment: There are many libraries that offer custom date formatting.  There are also polyfills for Intl.DateTimeFormat if you want to go that way.